# Dynamic height for an image using Tailwind and Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind with Next.js, and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically set the height for the "figure" element. Here's how I have it setup:

```
<figure className={format === "wide" ? wideImageClass : narrowImageClass}>
   <Image
     src={url}
     alt={alt}
     width={width}
     height={height}
     layout="fill"
     objectFit="contain"
   />
   <figcaption className="font-display text-sm text-gray-700">
     {caption}
   </figcaption>
 </figure>;
```

Here's what `narrowImageClass` would be. It's essentially computing the height of the image container.

```
  const narrowImageClass = `relative my-6 h-[${Math.round(
              (articleWidth * height) / width
            )}px]`;
```

When this renders into HTML the classes look correct, but the height of `figure` ends up being set to `0` and so nothing renders on my screen. Any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will be because you are using dynamic classnames. Tailwind will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.

As explained here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

The classnames need to be in the code somewhere, or you could look at adding them to your config as a safelist or regex.

Details here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes